# The installation of rn-fetch-blob fails to build my app

Tags: react-native, rn-fetch-blob

I am using React-native 0.62.2. Everything was working fine until I installed rn-fetch-blob. I tried to build my app by running react-native run-android but it failed to build. Instead I got the following error:

```
> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
161 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 158 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Unable to delete directory 

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 24s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Unable to delete directory
```

I am using gradle 6.3 and jdk 13.

Please can someone help me with this?

Comment: did you try usuals? 1. cleaning the gradle `cd android && ./gradlew clean` 2. removing `node_modules` and running `npm i`?

Comment: Thanks  senthil balaji. I just did all of that but same problem.